# FLEX-BASIS: 0; Alguien me puede solucionar?

Tags: css

en mi libro (Learning Web Design por Jeniffer Robbins), se explica que flex-basis:0; establece un flex absoluto. Que quiere decir exactamente eso. Gracias

Comment: Si el libro no te explica, cambia de libro. te sugiero altamente que veas los siguientes enlaces: para que realices preguntas con altas chances de respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + Documentación buenísima sobre desarrollo web: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox + https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> en este aprenderás el sito del sitio y de paso obtendrás tu primera medalla. Saludos y bienvenido/a a SOes :D